# Catching exceptions in tasks

Tags: .net, wpf, task-parallel-library

My base ViewModel, implemented a couple years ago, provides this extension method for running tasks while keeping the UI responsive*:

```
protected void Work(Action job)
{
    IsBusy = true;
    var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(job)
        .ContinueWith(failedTask => HandleException(failedTask, stackTrace), 
                      TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
        .ContinueWith(_ => { IsBusy = false; });
}

void HandleException(Task task, StackTrace stackTrace)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        () => { throw new Exception(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString() + 
                                    stackTrace); });
}
```

`IsBusy` is a property observed from the UI to display a progress bar.

The idea behind `HandleExceptions` is that they are observed and then thrown in the UI thread, caught by a `try/catch` block in the `Main()` method and logged before displaying a friendly message to the user and safely closing the app. The stackTrace is passed so the log includes the caller information.

However, I recently started getting reports of the application crashing without logging, nor friendly messages, with this Windows dialog:

[image: crash]

Looking at the Windows event log, we got this EventData:

> Application: xxxxApplication.Loader.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.AggregateException
>
> Stack: at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()

Am I doing anything wrong with `ContinueWith()`?

Is it possible for task exceptions to somehow stay unobserved?

---

<sub>*: I know about `BackgroundWorker`. This probably seemed like a better idea at the time, or had additional benefits.</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that `InnerException` is never null? Shouldn't you use [`InnerExceptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions.aspx) (and [`Flatten`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten.aspx)) instead?

Comment: @Mr.Steak good question. I **think** it was never null in this case, and Flatten shouldn't be needed because there's always a single exception being thrown (remember, the Task just calls a delegate, and there's no composition of any kind besides what's shown here)

Comment: I don't know for sure if the `InnerException` property is always `!= null`. But when it is `null`, the `HandleException` method itself will encounter a `NullReferenceException` on the `ToString()` call. Otherwise, accessing the `task.Exception` property should prevent the `AggreagteExpcetion`.

Comment: @Mr.Steak understood. It still looks unlikely under the described conditions. It's also an erratic behavior; I'd expect something more easily reproducible if it was just a null InnerException.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon When does this error occur? While the application is idling or when the user exits the application?

Comment: @FrancoisNel it occurs while the user is working with the app.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I would suggest you handle the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to either display your "friendly message" or (if this is not a solution for you) you could at least log the errors within this event and then see what the stacktrace is to determine where this "un-handled" task exception occurs.

Comment: @FrancoisNel I guess I could do that... I'm currently handling `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` only, because the exceptions were supposed to be dispatched to the UI thread. Wanna add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you handle the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) 
to either display your "friendly message" or (if this is not a solution for you) you could at least log the errors within this event and then see what the stacktrace is to determine where this "un-handled" task exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you've got a race condition here. From [Task.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) reference:

> Tasks that throw unhandled exceptions store the resulting exception and propagate it wrapped in a AggregateException in calls to Wait or in accesses to the Exception property. Any exceptions not observed by the time the task instance is garbage collected will be propagated on the finalizer thread. For more information and an example, see Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library).

Bottomline, if your task gets collected before the delegate passed in `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` gets invoked the exception will be thrown in the main thread. A quick fix:

```
void HandleException(Task task, StackTrace stackTrace)
{
    // "observe" the exception
    var ex = task.Exception;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        () => { throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.ToString() + 
                                    stackTrace); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual problem, fixed last year, turned out to be an issue with the notifications inside `IsBusy`

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure, but you would obtain the original exception through the `failedTask` variable. [It provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) a non-null `AggregateException` if the Task failed.

That Exception has in turn a [Handle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle.aspx) which you can provide a delegate where you can handle each Exception contained in the AggregateException and state whether you consider the exception handled or not.

In other words, if you want to rethrow the actual exception on the Dispatcher thread, I think you should make sure that you marked the original exception as *handled* before leaving the Task chain.

Comment: from what I've seen, `Handle` just rethrows an `AggregateException` with the exceptions that weren't "handled" by the predicate. It doesn't mark or unmark anything.

Comment: what do you mean with seen? I think I used the method to ensure that the exception does not get thrown (by returning true for handled from the handle-predicate), but I'd have to re-check.